# Animation works in FF but bad effect in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, animation

I have an 'absolute positioned' section that is hidden to the right of main content. Upon menu selection, I animate this section to the left as

```
mysection.stop().animate({
    left:'200px'
},2000,'easeOutBounce',function(){
    menuobj.css({
        borderLeft:'1px solid green',
        borderTop:'1px solid green',
        borderRight:'1px solid green',
        height:'-=1',
        width:'-=2'
    });
});
```

After animation, I'm adding a border for menu.
This worked perfectly before I add a flex slider in that section. After adding a jQuery flex slider inside that section, I got weird animation inside chrome. But works fine inside Firefox. Following is a screenshot of the effect from chrome.
[image: Before animation]

[image: During animation]

In the above pictures, the section is with gray background that I'm talking about.
Why this happens? Is there any specific hack for webkit?

**Edit**

I tested it in a high performance(Graphics card inserted) pc, and it works perfect :o

So, is it system dependent? I'm totally confused.

Comment: Is it online somewhere?

Comment: It would help to have a jsfiddle/plunkr with the minimum setup to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Without a posibility to reproduce this problem (jsfiddle, online version, etc.) no one will be able to help you i guess.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer : OK. I'll make it and inform here. After that please help me.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer: I made it online. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does the animation work properly in Chrome if you disable the flex slider?

If it does work OK without having the flex slider within the moving area, try waiting for the animation to complete before loading the flex slider in place. Not sure if this is possible for you, as we don't yet have a live test version to fiddle with. I would imagine it is possible, however.

If it works, you will probably have to disable the flex slider afterwards as well (when you want the animated area to go away). Having a thumbnail image in place within the animated area should allow you to maintain the look that it is "populated" with the slider while animating. If executed correctly, the user will never know that the slider only really showed up after the animation finished.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did as you said in the second paragraph. But don't know how to implement the things in 3rd paragraph. **How to disable the flex slider?** and **"Having a thumbnail image in place within the animated area", how?**

Comment: To make a thumbnail, just take a screenshot of the flex slider when it looks correct (in Firefox for example). Then crop out all the surrounding areas, leaving only the flex slider's images. Save that as an image and place the image within the animating panel during the animation. Then write some jQuery that will `hide()` the image when the animation has completed and `show()` the flex slider at that time.

Comment: Disabling the flex slider can be done a number of ways, but the most appropriate way will depend on how exactly you're making it show up in the first place. Off the top of my head, one idea would be to create a function - loadSlider(), for example - and make that function load all the necessary scripts, images, etc for the slider, and place the complete slider app into a predetermined html element. That same element would contain the thumbnail image when the animation is active, and would load the flex slider from loadSlider() when the animation is complete.

Comment: Another idea would be to load the slider as you do now, but simply `hide()` it before the animation starts and `show()` the thumbnail after the slider is hidden. Then carry out the animation. Once it is complete, reverse the process to `show()` the slider and `hide()` the thumbnail. I will also add that the thumbnail may not be necessary at all, I just thought it would create a sense of continuity while the animation was processing. You could also simply `hide()` the slider during animation and `fadeIn()` when it is completed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please inform me if you find a better solution(without hide n show).

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to you custom.js which apply a workaround. Not really a solution but looks better than at the moment. It hides the flexgallery on animation start and fades it back in on animation end.

**custom.js**

```
43: $('#nav li').click(function() {
44:     $('#ProjContent').hide(); // added
45:         var menuitem=$(this);
```

and

```
168: $('#ProjContent').hide(); // added
169:     maincontent.animate({top:0},2000,'easeOutBounce',function(){
170:         $('#ProjContent').fadeIn(250); // added
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Please inform me if you find a better solution(without hide n show).